# Simple script works and now it's in infinite loop [Service error: Spreadsheets]

Tags: google-apps-script

3 days ago script works smoothly without any problems, and today [script wasn't edited those days] it doesn't work anymore. Simple script like:

```
function plus() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
var currVal=s.getRange("M2").getValue()
var plusVal= currVal +1
s.getRange("M2").setValue(plusVal)
}
```

Now it seems like infinite loop, but after a while error appears:

```
Service error: Spreadsheets
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cannot reproduce, is it linked to a trigger?

Comment: The problem is that I just created new ss and function works smoothly. So the problem apparently appears directly in ss, but given the fact that only error I have is [Service error: Spreadsheets] I have no idea where to look for solution.

Comment: Spreadsheets sometimes brick like that unfortunately. I think the recommendation has always been to just create a copy of the spreadsheet as there is no obvious way to fix it.